# How to express the price of a unit of output

Tags: possessives

What are the differences in meaning between:

> 1. The output’s unit’s price
> 2. The unit output’s price or
> 3. Output unit’s price

My intention is to say:

> “The price of a unit of output”

Comment: The output's unit price is how I would express it, myself. 'Unit price' is a compound noun.

Comment: @Nigel J Though not in "the kitchen unit's price".

Answer (score -1):

You are chasing the possessive back to the creator of the process. 
You want the price of a quantity of output. The output is measured in units and so you have a price per unit. The proper term is the Output's Unit Price. That is the price for any unit that was produced.

If the last unit was very special then you could talk about that output unit's price and negotiate  a different price it.